# Codeigniter - sending data via URL and getting response

Tags: php, codeigniter

what i am trying to do is send some data to a url and get a response like "success" that indicates that data is received in codeigniter. Do i need to configure an api in the codeigniter to test that. I tried the following code but not getting the expected result. To mention I am pretty new in codeigniter and php.

controller xmlPost.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


Class XmlPost extends CI_controller
{

public function index()
{

$this->load->model('xml_model','message');

$this->message->source = "14045" ;
$this->message->dst = "08887654657";
$this->message->msg = "Hi, this is test";
$this->message->url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter1/index.php/receive';

$data = $this->message->Send();

echo $data;
    }
}
?>
```

and the model is xml_model.php

```
<?php

Class Xml_model extends CI_Model {

 var $source; //Source address
 var $dst; //Destination
 var $msg; // Message
 var $url;
 var $api_url;


  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
   }

  function Send(){

    $this->api_url = 'http://localhost/codeigniter1/index.php/receive';
    $params = $this->source.'&destinationaddr='.$this->dst.'&shortmessage='.urlencode($this->msg).' '.urlencode($this->url).'';

   $post_data = array(
     "sourceaddr" => $params,
    );

    $stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
    ),
   );

  $context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
  $response = file_get_contents($this->api_url, null, $context);
  return $response;
        }
      }

      ?>
```

Comment: you code is not like that what you want. In MVC you need to call a /controller/action/optional_parameters to get data.   
where is `codeigniter1/index.php/receive`?

Comment: receive.php is another controller in another site in thr htdocs directory of my xampp server and the new site is also codeigniter site @Riad

Comment: what is returned by `receive.php` ? you can directly call the page and see the output.

Comment: no the point is consider that receive.php is a controller of another site and when i send some data to receive.php it will do some validation with that data like if the received data is "123" then return a success message as response. And i don't want to use session library and redirect i.e. 

$this->session->set_flashdata('$my_var' , $data["id"]);
redirect('/receive/receive_finction/');

I want to accomplish that @Riad

Answer (score 1):

```
After url encoing Space[ ] can encoded as + sign.you have to manually replace as %20,then after execute your URL.
public function sendSMS($mobile,$code)
{

      $stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'GET',
        ),
    );
             $context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
     $url="http://api.smsbrain.in/1.2/appsms/send.php?user=satish123&passwd=123456&senderId=SATISH&recipients=".$mobile."&message=Your%20Verification%20code%20for%20facebook%20is%20".$code.".";
     //echo "URL".$url;
     $response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);


    echo print_r($response);

}
```